# How to join tables: Column equals value or is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure

Table1:

```
+--------+
| foo_id |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
+--------+
```

Table2:

```
+--------+--------+
| foo_id | bar_id |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      3 |
|      3 |      2 |
+--------+--------+
```

Now, I want an output like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| foo_id | bar_id |
+--------+--------+
|      1 | 1      |
|      2 | null   |
|      3 | null   |
+--------+--------+
```

What came to my mind was sth like

```
select table2.foo_id, table2.bar_id 
from table1
left join table2    on table1.foo_id = table2.foo_id
                       and table2.bar_id = 1
```

but it does not quite work, I get 3 lines for foo_id = 1.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much!

Comment: @Andrwe based on the join the OP wants the one where `bar_id=1`

Comment: What is the aim behind obtaining the output like that?

Comment: @DStanley, thanks, didn't see the second line of the join clause.

Comment: Lee's post below produces the desired result, but I still don't see where you're getting 3 rows for foo_id of 1, basedon the posted query.

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/2751573/andrew You are right, Sorry. I oversimplified a bit I think. However, Lee got it right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to change from:

```
select table2.foo_id, table2.bar_id 
from table1
left join table2    on table1.foo_id = table2.foo_id
                       and table2.bar_id = 1
```

to

```
select table1.foo_id, table2.bar_id 
from table1
left join table2    on table1.foo_id = table2.foo_id
                       and table2.bar_id = 1
```

You mistakenly chose the wrong table to output foo_id from

Comment: Spot on.  Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dd4bf/4) showing the results of the two queries.

Comment: also, thanks for the comment with the sqlfiddle. didnt know that site either

Answer (score -1):

```
select table2.foo_id, table2.bar_id 
from table1
left join table2    on table1.foo_id = table2.foo_id
where table2.bar_id = 1 or table2.bar_id is null
```

Comment: That would drop the row where `foo_id=3` from the output.

Comment: I don't think so @DStanley, that row is selected by the join and has a null value in table2.bar_id

Comment: Don't think. Try it. `table2.bar_id` is 2 for `foo_id` = 3

Comment: @isalgueiro It would be selected by the join but would be filtered out by the `where` because `bar_id` is not `1` or `null`.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Anyway it seems that OP wants a left join where talbe2.bar_id is 1 or null, so I'm still thinking this SQL is right

Comment: @isalgueiro It's not right if the OP wants a row where `foo_id=3` in the output.